# Copy Rotation not resetting normally to the original pose?

Tags: rigging, constraints

So I added two Copy rotation to the bone wrist, and when I rotate and try to reset the pose with Alt+R/G/S, it's necessary to press these commands several times to go back to the original position, instead of hitting those keys just once. And sometimes the bone just spin crazily.

It's normal? Or I need something like controls to make it work?

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you've created a dependency loop.  You need to have a clear hierarchy in your rig: if your finger depends on your hand, your hand cannot also depend upon your finger.

Comment: May I ask how to do that?

Comment: Don't make things depend in loops.  If finger is parented to hand, or has any constraints or drivers targeting hand, it depends on hand; if it depends on hand, hand cannot also depend on finger.  This is true of all bones and objects, not just hand and finger or whatever.  When you build a rig, you need to be paying attention to the relationships you're creating so that you have a clear idea, this depends on that which depends on that, so that you don't create those kinds of loops.

Comment: Oh nice, I get it now and it works. Thank you very much!